# Perl module Image::Magick::Q16::constant missing on working Image::Magick?

Tags: perl, imagemagick, cpan

I am the author of CPAN module Image::Hash. It is a module for doing image hashing and uses GD, Image::Magick or Imager to work with images, depending on what that is installed on a users system.

I test to see if Image::Magick is installed by wrapping it in a eval like this:

```
eval { require Image::Magick};
```

If Image::Magick is installed the module will use it.

This has been working great, but lately so have I gotten two error report from CPAN testers where my module fails with error *"Image::Magick::Q16::constant not defined"*.

Dos this means that you can have Image::Magick installed, but still not have a working environment because Image::Magick::Q16 is missing?

How do I handle this?

I do not want to add  Image::Magick::Q16: as a requirement for everyone, because it works correctly without it on all but two platforms.

The CPAN testers reports:

Image-Hash-0.06:

- x86_64-linux-thread-multi / 5.18.1:
- FAIL http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/822fb984-965b-11e5-8cc0-4f581fbf4db7

Image-Hash-0.06:

- i486-linux-thread-multi / 5.18.1:
- FAIL http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/1a701ba4-97fa-11e5-975f-b301d0c0c177

Just to clarify; according to  CPAN testers my module works on 215 platforms, and fails on 2. So this is not a common error. I do not currently have easy access to a machine with perl 5.18.1.

Comment: One could install the Q8 version of ImageMagick instead of the usual Q16, and get the error message they are seeing.  I suspect that Q16 has been installed on all but two of the platforms you tested, so it would be safe to go ahead and require Image::Magick::Q16 as a requirement.

Comment: I have investigated this further and there is no cpan package named Image::Magick::Q16 (nor Image::Magick::Q8 or Image::Magick::Q32). This named must be internal to Image::Magick. That means that adding Image::Magick::Q16 as a requirement will not fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> Dos this means that you can have Image::Magick installed, but still not have a working environment because Image::Magick::Q16 is missing?

Correct. Quantum constants are defined during compile time of ImageMagick's library . To quote [PerlMagicks Overview document](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#overview).

> PerlMagick is *quantum* aware. You can request a specific quantum depth when you instantiate an image object:
>
> ```
> use Image::Magick::Q16;
> $image = Image::Magick::Q16->new;
> ```

I'm not familiar with Perl, but I can see that the specific quantum-constant would be [defined here](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/22d1e094559e53ee6661c2b361343153a3c402d8/PerlMagick/quantum/quantum.pm.in#L1).

```pl
package Image::Magick::@MAGICK_ABI_SUFFIX@;
```

Where `@MAGICK_ABI_SUFFIX@` can be influenced by `--with-quantum-depth` & `--enable-hdri`. See [Advanced Unix Installation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php)

So the following packages could be valid ...

- `Image::Magick::Q8`
- `Image::Magick::Q16`
- `Image::Magick::Q32`

And *perhaps* with an additional `HDRI` suffix.